# how to simplify this equation

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

Problem: Given a number between 0 and 6, which combination of 4, 2, 1 will equal the given number. A number can only be used once (cannot just do 1 for 6 times to get a given number of 6).

```
Examples:
Value = 6
4 = 1
2 = 1
1 = 0

Value = 4
4 = 1
2 = 0
1 = 0

Value = 3
4 = 0
2 = 1
1 = 1

Current forumlas, where given number is 6:
4 = Floor(6/4)
2 = Floor(6%4)/2
1 = Floor[(6%4)%2]/1
```

Given that this is a pattern, how would I simplify my formulas?
Does this pattern have any particular name?

Comment: Have you ever seen bit representation of integer numbers?

Comment: Nope never seen before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow a greedy approach. Start subtracting the largest element in the list (4-2-1 here) that is also smaller than the number you want to decompose from your number and repeat until you reach 0.